# User Interface of an iOS apps seems to be enlarged for unknown reason

Tags: ios, iphone

I took over two iOS projects from my predecessor in the company and I have some problems with one of the apps.
The program works correctly, but compared to other apps the graphical interface of the second app seems somehow enlarged.

The navigation bar is higher, the text in the navigation bar is larger. Text in table cells is larger. Even UISwitch objects are larger. I guess around 50%.

I can't find a reason for this different appearance in the code. Even if I drag a new UISwitch onto a view it is bigger than in other apps or bigger than the switches in the iOS settings.

Is there a global setting that enlarges the complete view of an app?

Comment: is size larger in storyboard while developing or while running the application? can you share some screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a image file named Default.png, Default@2x.png or Default-568h@2x.png in the project?
If yes, remove that image from the project may help.

Comment: I removed all the images and added a Launch-Storyboard. Everything is fine now. Thanks!